# XlsxWriter is only writing first row for each list of objects passed

Tags: python, iteration, xlsxwriter

I am working exporting a page report that gets broken down into 3 smaller subsets. However, the structure of each object inside each list makes the xlsxwriter *enumerate* function think this is the only item iterable, and only writes one row.

Below is a structure of a single list of objects (passed to the writer), and one object itself.

Almost certain it's the object structure that is breaking the desired output, but in case anyone sees something else don't hesitate!

Thanks!

List:

```
[<Page: badges : Badges : me>, <Page: badges : Badges : me>, <Page: badges : Badges : me>], [<Page: badges : Badges : me>, <PageTracking: badges : Badges : me>, <Page: badges : Badges : me>]
```

Single object in list:

```
<Page: badges : Badges : me>
```

Code to split list into group of 3 sublists:

```
all_pages = Page.objects.all()
page_groups = [all_pages[x:x+2] for x in xrange(0, len(all_pages), 2)]
```

XlsxWriter code:

```
def WriteToExcel(page_chunk, workbook):

if page_chunk is not None:
    print "WriteToExcel ----- triggered \n"
    try:
        # output = StringIO.StringIO()
        workbook = workbook

        worksheet_s = workbook.add_worksheet("Summary")
        title = workbook.add_format({
            'bold': True,
            'font_size': 14,
            'align': 'center',
            'valign': 'vcenter'
        })
        header = workbook.add_format({
            'bg_color': '#F7F7F7',
            'color': 'black',
            'align': 'center',
            'valign': 'top',
            'border': 1
        })
        title_text = ("Report For Page")
        worksheet_s.merge_range('B2:H2', title_text, title)
        worksheet_s.set_column(0, 6, 12)
        worksheet_s.write(4, 0, ("#"), header)
        worksheet_s.write(4, 1, ("ID"), header)
        worksheet_s.write(4, 2, ("Page Type"), header)
        worksheet_s.write(4, 3, ("Page Name"), header)
        worksheet_s.write(4, 4, ("User Email"), header)
        worksheet_s.write(4, 5, ("Date Visited"), header)

        for idx, data in enumerate(page_chunk):
            print "data ---------- %s" %(data)
            row = 5 + idx
            worksheet_s.write_number(row, 0, idx + 1)
            worksheet_s.write(row, 1, data.pk)
            worksheet_s.write(row, 2, data.page_type)
            worksheet_s.write(row, 3, data.page_name)
            worksheet_s.write(row, 4, data.user_email)
            worksheet_s.write(row, 5, data.date_visited)

        workbook.close()
    except:
        log.debug("Worksheet write has failed --> page_chunk handed to function %s", page_chunk)
        return False
```

Spreadsheet output:
[image]

Comment: Could you also post the code how do you write the lists into excel? Thanks.

Comment: @Alecxe was just about to! One minute.

Comment: @alecxe - Had started to wonder if enumerate isn't the write method in this case? Or with the object structure as it is, I'm not listing enough arguments to it beforehand?

Comment: @alecxe - Found the real issue and it's a duplicate! Marked it as such.

Comment: @alecxe - can I not mark my own question a dup? I went through with the request but it shows your as the marker.

Comment: You should be able to do so, I can unduplicate it if you want, not a problem. Thanks.

Comment: Ah no worries at all @alecxe, guessing your request just went through before mine. Cheers!